# What is the process for reporting an app with a stolen icon?

Tags: software-center, legal

Today I found an application in the Ubuntu Software Center called EasyAdmin.  This application uses the iOS settings icon.  How do I report this?

Comment: You'd have to report that to Apple so Apple's legal team can go after them.  (Note: I am not a lawyer)

Comment: And if it's the opposite?

Comment: There is one issue here, as well.  The software is listed as "proprietary" and you have to pay for it to get the software.  I also believe, therefore, that to get this resolved, Apple would have to go after the providers of the software and pursue them for trademark and copyright infringement.  I'm not sure if Ubuntu can do anything about it.

Comment: I sent a complaint to Apple, but I think it would be better if Canonical took it down on their own without having to go through any legal hassle.

Comment: Ubuntu still polices these apps. Simply open a support ticket with pay-support@canonical.com and they will handle notifying the developer.